# Storing results of BFG to new project in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I've successfully (I think!) removed large files from a gitlab project mirrored on my local drive using BFG.  I don't want to replace the existing gitlab project (for safety reasons), but instead want to push to a new test gitlab project.  Here's the commands I've done successfully so far:

```
git clone --mirror git@git.domain.com:architecture-team/IOMobile.git
java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M IOMobile.git/
cd IOMobile.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Those commands seem to have done the trick, now how do I reset the origin to:

```
git@git.domain.com:architecture-team/testiomobile.git
```

...and then push the mirror into the new project?  I'm not sure how to reset the origin on a mirror and want to make sure I don't change the original project.

Do I just do a simple

```
git push
```

or do I need

```
git push --mirror
```

Thanks for any help
-Owen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case it does not matter if you specify `--mirror` or not. Since you cloned it already with the `--mirror` flag, a normal git push will update all refs on the remote server. This is also described at the bfg docs: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

But there is a gotcha you could run into. If you see this error message while pushing:

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
```

Then you have to enable `Allow force push` option in the GitLab project settings at URL https://git.domain.com/architecture-team/testiomobile/-/settings/repository

[image]

After the push you should disable the `Allow force push` again.